# How to install nvidia on ubuntu dual boot?

Tags: nvidia, 20.04, graphics

I have installed ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot in my computer. But the ubuntu os have intel graphics. I am trying to install nvidia but i am worrying about harm my win10 os.

```
sudo apt purge nvidia-*
```

If I run this command does it remove nvidia from my win10 os? Can anyone help me about installing nvidia on ubuntu dual boot?

Comment: Why do you assume an OS can be affected by the software on another OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about when installing or removing software from Ubuntu. This will not affect Windows at all, as the two systems operate independently from each other.

The easiest way to install the Nvidia drivers would be to use the "Additional Drivers" tool:

1. Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> (Windows) key and type "Driver"
2. Click the "Additional Drivers" tab (if it's not already selected). Depending on which video card you have installed, you will be presented with a list of one or more drivers.
   [image: Additional Drivers]
3. Select the NVIDIA diver you want to install and click on "Apply Changes"
4. Once the drivers are installed, reboot your machine

That's all there is to it.

After rebooting, you can access the Nvidia settings application by opening Terminal and typing this:

```
sudo nvidia-settings
```

This will open an application in `sudo` mode, allowing you to make changes to how and when your video card operates.

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings]

Hope this helps